# how can I use Convert.toDecimal with databinding

Tags: wpf, xaml, devexpress

I've try this

```
<dxe:SpinEdit EditValue="{Binding Entity.MaxValue, Converter=Convert.ToDecimal}" />
```

but this show me an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a converter class. So create a class Implement IValueConverter,

```
    public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
    {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,     CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return System.Convert.ToDecimal(value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then is xaml declare it within your resources and call it

```
<UserControl.Resources>
<local:MyConverter x:Key="MyConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

   <dxe:SpinEdit EditValue="{Binding Entity.MaxValue, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}" />
```

Comment: thank you, Convert.ToDecimal is already a IValueConverter. why can't use it directly? or I'm missing something.

Comment: @AbderrahimDz24 "Convert.ToDecimal is already a IValueConverter". No, it isn't.

Comment: I am not aware of IValueConverter for decimal conversion which already exists. But if there is one, you just have to declare it within your usercontrol resources and then you can use it. Convert.ToDecimal this is a c# method not xaml. See my update.

Comment: @Clemens when I hover Convert.toDecimal it show me IValueConverter this is why I think it is.

Comment: In this case it shows you a tooltip of what you need, and not what it is, you can put any text like foo and it will still show IValueConverter :)